How I can re-enable USB Port after the OS disable them without reboot?
How I can re-enable access to usb port after the OS disable them after an unsecure unplug?
I am using Arch linux , sometimes after using a port for a long time the port become unusable, and I only can use it after I reboot the computer.
How I can make it enable back again without a hard reboot?

is a     Hardware detector installed ie usbguard?
